# COUNTIFS: criteria either date or blank

Tags: excel, countif

I have a table that contains all services provided to customers. It has many columns, but the important ones for this question are the following: StartDate & EndDate.

Im trying to count the number over services provided pr. month 2016.

So far I have tried using the COUNTIFS function

`=COUNTIFS(Table[StartDate];"<="&DATE($H$1;I2;1);Table[EndDate];">="&DATE($H$1;I2+1;0))`

Where H1 contains the Year (2016), and I2 contains the month (1).

**The problem:** It only counts services that were active before the selected month - that has an EndDate. But I also want to count the number of Services that does not have an EndDate (blank).

Basicly I want something like this:

`=COUNTIFS(Table[StartDate];"<="&DATE($H$1;I2;1);
Table[EndDate];">="&DATE($H$1;I2+1;0) OR Table[EndDate]; "")`

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try: `=SUM(COUNTIFS(Table[StartDate];"<="&DATE($H$1;I2;1);Table[EndDate];{">="&DATE($H$1;I2+1;0),"="})`  May need to be entered as an array formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.

Comment: @ScottCraner Didnt work, just threw an error - and looks like Excel dislikes that im using ">="&DATE. According to documentation I can find, it seems as though you have to use the following: Table[EndDate];{"criteria","criteria2"}. Ergo using the " as part of the first criteria, seems to make it struggle.

Comment: Then split them into two separate countifs and add them together.

Comment: @ScottCraner Simple and good suggestion, I like it. However it didnt yield the expected result. AXTable[EndDate];"" does not equal blank it seems..